# Cannot run mongod using `service mongod start`

Tags: mongodb

`service mongod start` is not working

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-12-12 13:03:34 UTC; 56s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 3024 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 3024 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 12 13:03:34 moonboy-mongodb systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Dec 12 13:03:34 moonboy-mongodb mongod[3024]: {"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:03:34.708Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"e>
Dec 12 13:03:34 moonboy-mongodb systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 12 13:03:34 moonboy-mongodb systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

However executing `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` directly work fine.

---

Dig into the log both of them keep looping this 10-11 times

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.697+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.697+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.697+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.700+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.700+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.708+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.708+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.708+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.708+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.708+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":3298,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/mnt/moonboy_mongodb_volume/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"moonboy-mongodb"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.708+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.5","gitVersion":"d65fd89df3fc039b5c55933c0f71d647a54510ae","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.708+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.708+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"0.0.0.0","port":27017},"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/mnt/moonboy_mongodb_volume/data/db","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:14.709+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.298+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23377,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Received signal","attr":{"signal":2,"error":"Interrupt"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.298+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23380,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Signal was sent by the kernel"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.298+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23381,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"will terminate after current cmd ends"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.298+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.298+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.298+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.298+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.298+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784903, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the LogicalSessionCache"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.299+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.302+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23017,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"removing socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784908, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784909, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784910, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784911, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Enqueuing the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784912, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Killing all operations for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4695300, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Interrupted all currently running operations","attr":{"opsKilled":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":5093807, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down all TenantMigrationAccessBlockers on global shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784913, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down all open transactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784914, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Acquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":4784915, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the IndexBuildsCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784916, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Reacquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784917, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Attempting to mark clean shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20609,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":3684100, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down TTL collection monitor thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":3684101, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down TTL collection monitor thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784930, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the storage engine"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22320,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22321,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22322,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22323,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20282,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Deregistering all the collections"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22261,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Timestamp monitor shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22317,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22318,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22319,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.303+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.304+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1639314677:304453][3201:0x7f7e5eab5700], close_ckpt: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 19, snapshot max: 19 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 30503411"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.348+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":45}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.348+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22279,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.348+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.348+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.348+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20626,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.350+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:17.350+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":0}}
```

But by running `mongod` directly it eventually stops to have the below log and successfully run the `mongod`.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:42.314+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23377,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Received signal","attr":{"signal":2,"error":"Interrupt"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:42.314+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23380,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Signal was sent by the kernel"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:42.314+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23381,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"will terminate after current cmd ends"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-12T13:11:42.314+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
```

Comment: Check file `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` if you have any other options in there. By default `service mongod start` starts the service as root, while `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` runs under current user. In order to change the user see https://superuser.com/questions/1098167/how-to-run-service-not-as-root

Comment: `:"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"` indicates that you try to start the service more than once.

Comment: "By default service mongod start starts the service as root" Look like it's opposite.
I'm running `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` as root but when I changed to other user it get the same error as `service mongod start`

Comment: Yeah, Changing the User to root inside `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` will work. So I think the issue might be setting up the mongod to be able to run using non-root.

Comment: Okay worked now, Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit for the correct hint.
So I'm not sure what happens but it's always worked previously until now.
Fixed by `sudo chmod -R` for username `mongodb` to db path and log path.

Comment: Usually you should not edit the `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` file. Instead make a copy of it to `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` and modify this copy. Otherwise when you make an update of Mongodb then the package manager may overwrite the service file and revert to default.

Comment: Yes, I done that for the debugging purpose. Now have reverted and allow mongod itself to be able to call from non-root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is for other people who encountered this.

So basically `service mongod start` didn't run using root user.

And I don't know when it have been changed.

However you need to lookup the user in `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`

In my case is `mongodb`

Then run

`sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb {your_log_path} {your_db_path}`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ubuntu please run this command

```
$ ls -ls /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
$ sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
$ sudo service mongod start
$ ls -lsah /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```